# How to teach a dog how to bark?

Tags: dogs, training, vocalizations

I have a 5 year old male German Shorthair Pointer / Black Lab mix. When I let him outside, I would like him to bark to get back in, so that if I am not in the room to let him in, I could hear him bark. We have gotten him there partially, except he doesn't really bark. He just whines at the door and scratches it, until about 10 minutes have passed. Then he will bark. I have tried getting a treat and putting it on my chin, as suggested by a book I read. I have praised him when he does bark. However, he continues to whine when he is at the door. What are some other things I could try to make my dog bark?

Answer (score 10):

If your teach your dog how to bark on command then it will be easier to teach him to bark when he wants to come in.

Teaching your dog to bark on command will require a lot of patience and dedication.

METHOD 1

- Firstly, pick a command that will be suitable and comfortable for you to use like "Bark", "Speak", "Yes", etc.
- Hold a toy that makes your dog and call the command to make your dog bark. Once he barks, give him the toy along with treats and praise him.

Repeat the process in 2 for a few times. Very soon he will get used to the command and understand what you want him to do.

- Try saying the command without holding the toy and see if he responds, if he does reward him with a lot of praises and treats. If he doesn't, Repeat the process in 2 again.

METHOD 2

- Pick a command that will be suitable for you to use like "Bark", "Speak", "Yes", etc.
- Put your dog in a situation of frustration because frustration will likely lead him to barking. An Example is tying him and going to a corner and calling his name. He will try to break loose and come and meet you, since he cannot he will most likely start to bark. Another example is tying him and then putting a favorite toy close to him (but not within his reach). This will most likely cause him to bark.
- Try putting the command before your dog barks. When he barks praise him with treats

(Continue the process in 2 until your dog is now regularly barking. Very soon he will realise what you want him to do and will bark once you give the command).

Once you have trained your dog to bark on command, whenever he is at the door and doesn't bark, Give him the command and once he barks, open the door and praise him. Repeat this for a few times and soon your dog will get used to it and will bark when he is at the door even without you giving him the command.

---

[This video on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=toN-xuTAQhk) might also help you to learn to train your dog to bark on command.

References :

1. [How to Teach a Dog to Bark at a Stranger](http://dogcare.dailypuppy.com/teach-dog-bark-stranger-1775.html)
2. [How to Train Your Dog to Bark on Command](http://www.ehow.com/how_14237_train-dog-bark.html)
3. [Teaching Your Dog to Bark on Command](http://www.thedogtrainingsecret.com/blog/teaching-dog-bark-command/)